# Cant adopt geometry in Mysql 8.0 to connect with qGIS

Tags: mysql, geometry, concatenation, qgis

I am developing a groundwater information system using mysql 8.0 workbench as my database developer and qGIS for visualising. I am new to both and had problems connecting with qGIS. My database is now connected to qGIS, However, I can't put my geometry on the shape file of qGIS although I have simple columns óf X and Y coords. I tried to add column to in my table.e.g alter table msc_project
add column geom Geometry  SRID 31467; and then concat the x and y .e.g. select CONCAT(XCoord, ',', YCoord) as geom from msc_project;. This does not work, the concat only results in combined values which cannot be seen in the table while geom  results in NULL. Answers and ideas would be appreciated Thanks.

P.S: I am importing data from excel sheet, the sheet has X and Y coordinates from Guasss-Kueger coordinate system. I used a shape file that select it.

Comment: Which version of MySql do you use? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Hi, I am using Mysql 8.0 CE. I edited just now,